# Regex: how to remove single characters that are not words?

Tags: python, regex, text, data-cleaning

I feel like this must have been asked elsewhere, but to the best of my ability I have not found a similar question here or elsewhere online.

In Python, when I was cleaning up a long text file, and had a long list of `regex` commands at the ready, I eventually saw that single-character words, like `"I"` or `"a"`, were unfortunately being deleted.

Is there a way, with `regex` (or something else), to perform the following operation?

```
re.sub(r"\non-word-single-character", "", "I want a b c cat")
"I want a cat"
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By elimination, a, i, o, u, v are the only ones used in text-speak (o : Oh!, u : you, v : we), other than that no other alphabet makes any sense in one letter, right?

Comment: Hmm, I guess a comprehensive mapping would have to be used, that would match all likely non-l33t-speak, non-shortened phrases and replace them with the intended actual words, and also match where solitary characters are just that, and delete those. I wonder if someone has attempted such a task already (probably some nlp library somewhere I imagine); I will have to look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple and elegant solution to your problem IMHO. The `\\b` signifies the word boundary.

**Code:**

```py
import re
re.sub('\\b[^(aiouvAIOUV)]{1} \\b', '', "I want a b c cat")
```

**Output:**

```
'I want a cat'
```

Comment: Thanks! I was looking at your comment and playing around with your solution, and wondering why `re.sub(r"\s[^aiouv0-9]\s", " ", "I want a b c cat 2")` wasn't working and was creating `''I want a c cat 2'`, but I think it has to do with you using `\\b` and also not using `r`?

Comment: ```\\b``` is a word-break, nothing new there. it's got an official name which I can't seem to remember now. ```r'khskd'``` is raw string which defeats the purpose here. So.

Comment: If there a lot of letters to include and the case didn't matter, a small tweak for the code would be to add 0, re.IGNORECASE to the end of re.sub and change aiouvAIOUV to aiouv. 0 means change all instances of the regex (the default behavior,) and re.IGNORECASE is a flag to, well, ignore the case.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that regex is a right tool for this. You need to recognize if a token is a valid word in a natural language.Regex does not provide tools for natural language processing. You'd rather use a dictionary or an NLP library to recognize valid words.